# Can't Extract work with All?

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got a data structure that consists of a long list of triples; each triple consists of a number, a two-element pair, and a two-element pair. Symbolically, I can represent this data structure as `{{t1, {x1, y1}, {vx1, vy1}}, {t2, {x2, y2}, {vx2, vy2}}, ...}`.

I want to extract just the tN and yN values as pairs, to end up with a list like this: `{{t1, y1}, {t2, y2}, ...}`. I can think of several ways to do this, including: pulling the tN out into one variable, the yN out into another, packaging the two together into a list, and transposing; or, flattening and using `Part`. However, the outermost list is likely to be very long, and I want to minimize list rearrangement and copying.

It seems like `Extract` should do the job. And it would, too, except that it throws an error whenever I try to use `All` as a position specification. When I try this:

```
traj = {{t1, {x1, y1}, {vx1, vy1}}, {t2, {x2, y2}, {vx2, vy2}}, {t3, {x3, y3}, {vx3, vy3}}};
Extract[traj, {{All, 1}, {All, 2, 2}}]
```

I get a "Position specification… is not applicable" error. The same thing happens if I try the `;;` syntax. However, the following work (although they only produce one pair, not the entire list of pairs):

```
Extract[traj, {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}]
(* ==> {t1, y1} *)

Extract[traj, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 2, 2}}]
(* ==> {t3, y3} *)
```

The best solution I've come up with so far is:

```
Extract[traj, {{#, 1}, {#, 2, 2}}] & /@ Range[Length[traj]]
```

But the question remains: Is there no way to make `Extract` take `All`, or something that has the equivalent functionality? I am flabbergasted that `Extract` differs from `Part` in this one small but important way.

Comment: What an interesting variety of solutions! I accepted @chuy's because I find it the most transparently readable (especially with infix notation for `Map`). I admit I haven't done careful timing comparisons yet for performance.

Comment: `Extract[traj, {{All, 1}, {All, 2, 2}}]` works as desired  in version 13.3 (perhaps in earlier versions too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yet another way using the operator form of `Extract`:

```
Map[Extract[{{1}, {2, 2}}], traj]
(* {{t1, y1}, {t2, y2}, {t3, y3}} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use destructuring.

```
helper[{t_, {_, y_}, _}] := {t, y}
helper /@ traj
```

> `{{t1, y1}, {t2, y2}, {t3, y3}}`

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this with `Part` (shorthand [[ ]]) rather than `Extract`:

```
Thread[{traj[[All, 1]], traj[[All, 2, 2]]}]
{{t1, y1}, {t2, y2}, {t3, y3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MapAt` is the only function I know that allows a list position to contain `All`. You could exploit that fact:

```
Reap[MapAt[Sow, traj, {{All, 1}, {All, 2, 2}}]][[2, 1]]
```

However, I like the following workaround better:

```
traj[[Sequence @@ #]] & /@ {{All, 1}, {All, 2, 2}}
```

Comment: `Transpose[traj[[##]] & @@@ {{All, 1}, {All, 2, 2}}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{t1, {x1, y1}, {vx1, vy1}}, {t2, {x2, y2}, {vx2, vy2}}, {t3, {x3, y3}, {vx3, vy3}}};
```

I would probably use

```
Cases[{a_, b_, _} :> {a, b[[2]]}] @ list
```

{{t1, y1}, {t2, y2}, {t3, y3}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = { {t1, {x1, y1}, {vx1, vy1}}, 
         {t2, {x2, y2}, {vx2, vy2}},
         {t3, {x3, y3}, {vx3, vy3}} };
```

Using `Most` and `Last`:

```
f = Function[x, Last @@@ Most@x];

f /@ list

(*{{t1, y1}, {t2, y2}, {t3, y3}}*)
```